# The system cannot find the file specified using FileInputStream, in java

Tags: java, file, system, fileinputstream

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Bitmapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // Handling binary (not text) data, so use FileInputStream
        try {
            FileInputStream in  = new FileInputStream("input.bmp");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.bmp");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("The System cannot find file");}
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        while((i=in.read())!=-1) {
            if (++counter>54)   // skip past Bitmap headers
            {
                i = Math.min(i+100, 255); // Lighten image
            }
            out.write(i);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

This is a code that my professor showed in class, however, I was not there to see how he fixed it, and he is not available for contact at this time.

What I tried:
 ClassLoader.getResource("/input.bmp") or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()

and also:

Bitmapper.class.getResource("\input.bmp");

and a few other methods.

The error I keep receiving (if I take out the "try"):
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.bmp (The system cannot find the file specified)

I promise I tried to search as thoroughly as possible for a similar situation on this site, but unfortunately have not come across a solution yet. Please help if possible, and thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Ah, file errors, my old friend.

Comment: but did you search if file `input.bmp` really exist in your application folder?

Comment: Try absolute path at FileInputStream, like "C:\input.bmp"

Comment: When you get an exception. print *its* message. Not your own. In this case that will tell you *which* of the two files it's talking about.